# How to query data about Amazon Athena itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Are there any internal tables that we can query inside Athena that will give us info about the usage of Athena?

I am looking for data like:

- Which queries are saved?
- Which user queried what and when?

I know there are hidden fields like `$path`, but I wonder if there are hidden tables about metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Amazon Athena is not like a traditional database.

Instead, this information is accessible via AWS AP requests, eg:

- [list-named-queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/list-named-queries.html) can retrieve a list of query IDs
- [get-named-query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/get-named-query.html) can then return information about a specific query
- [list-query-executions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/list-query-executions.html) returns a list of IDs for executed queries
- [get-query-execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/get-query-execution.html) can be used to obtain details of the query that was executed

However, the query execution details does *not* show which user executed the query. Instead, you can obtain such information from **AWS CloudTrail**, which keeps track of API calls made to almost every AWS service (not just Athena). The CloudTrail record will include the `queryExecutionId`, which can be used in `get-query-execution` (above) to retrieve details of the query.